# Could we get question block considered to be enabled for our stack?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We get a number of quite hardcore "help vampires" here, and I feel these users really get on peoples' nerves.

Given that suspension is quite an extreme measure, we mods are hesitant to use this punishment lightly. It might be good to have the [question block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) enabled, since it is an impersonal and automated mechanism which [kicks in after a certain pattern of behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). (Note that this is only [one tool of many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84668/how-does-stack-overflow-attempt-to-prevent-low-quality-questions-and-answers) that the Stack Exchange sites use to encourage/maintain high quality Q&A.)

Thoughts? Do you think this would be an appropriate feature to have on our site?

Comment: Just don't send them over to IRC, we are up to the gills in help vampires.

Comment: We could just migrate all of those questions to meta.so to illustrate our need. :D

Answer (score 9):

Considering how often we're dealing with a few of these "help vampires," I think this is a well overdue feature :)