# Danger of being blocked from asking questions

Tags: discussion, support

I came across [this](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/could-we-get-question-block-considered-to-be-enabled-for-our-stack) question and you guys here are successful in bringing this feature.
Here is the message that shows up when you are about to ask a question which I think is good.

[image]

The help section says the reason for blocking a particular user is not disclosed. Is it not a bit offending? In my case, I wasn't a good questioner and asked 1 or 2 poor questions in my initial phase. But I have been contributing to the community or at-least trying to!

So if I am blocked from asking questions, don't I deserve to know the criteria?
Isn't it scaring away future (top)contributors?

Comment: Hello Sri. I only see [one question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/110643/13418) initiated by yourself. It may not be that well explained a problem, however I don't see this as grounds for receiving that warning, unless I am missing something. In any event, please read the guide on asking good questions and consult the help section of the site [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) and most of all keep on contributing, asking questions and providing answers. You will be guided by members if there are problems.

Comment: @userabuser I hope I have improved If I were to ask a question. As you said I just have one question and I still get that warning. I panicked and deleted my other questions though!

Comment: @sri You can undelete those that you deleted yourself. We can do that for you as well. You just have to ask :)

Comment: well if there is no use to the community, then what's the point? ;) thanks kaiser for offering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several questions, most of which were deleted. Some were deleted by yourself, some were deleted by the community, most were closed or marked as duplicates.

With this in mind the automated system has picked up on it and given you a friendly warning. If a user is seeing that warning they can use the links to see what makes a good question and improve their questions so that they're less likely to be closed ( and get more attention and **up votes** ).

If you do get blocked asking questions, it will be because you haven't shown a sufficient improvement. You may have a different opinion, but the system doesn't deal with opinions, it works off of data. If you're stuggling to form well written on topic answers and need help, we're always available to give it in chat and elsewhere.

As for offence, people get offended, and there's not a lot that can be done about that in some cases. At the end of the day people can be offended by anything and anybody, and you have no intrinsic right to not be offended. In this case, you would have been offended by a computer program

[For more information on the question block see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294)

Comment: Fair enough! And thanks for removing those numbers from your answer.

Comment: @sri The "numbers" you are referring to, are visible for anyone [above 10k reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Visible deleted questions and answers are a "privilege" that is earned with that amount of reputation.

Comment: @sri Actually, the numbers are now visible to anyone who cares to look at the history of Tom's answer. Before that, they were only visible to moderators — or to anyone who cares to investigate a bit with the help of Google and the Internet Archive, or who happens to have old Stack Exchange dumps stashed somewhere.

Comment: @kaiser Users with 10k reputation can view deleted posts if they happen to land on them, but they cannot search for them, and they won't see them listed in a user's profile.

Comment: @Gilles So I think my WPSE history is no secret any more :( lol

Comment: @Gilles I tried to clear that up in TL chat room and this was the answer given to me. Anyway, the number isn't completely hidden (more like obfuscated and hard to find), so Tom gladly didn't disclose any information. Thanks for jumping in.

Comment: @sri My apologies, it should not have happened. I advise a flurry of brilliant questions and answers with lots of up votes to remedy the situation

Comment: @TomJNowell No need for an apology :) I will try to contribute as much as I can.

Comment: @sri Just my two cents here.  Readers and Posters alike on any of the SE Network expect well researched, well thought out questions.  Usually, that type of question takes anywhere from 30 minutes to an hour to formulate, 15 to 45 if you're a fast typer.  Google, a text editor and a tabbed browser are your friend here.  As an example look here: [Quickest Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309978/quickest-algorithm-for-this-interesting-occurence/24319424).  Research took me an hour to plot out and an hour to type, with one hand.

Comment: Said effort should also be exerted in any attempt to solve a problem before coming here, if only for ones personal development